# How to specify more than one named Servlet to be wrapped by a filter?

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

How to specify more than one named Servlet to be wrapped by a filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map a filter to one or more servlets (and you can map more than one filter to a servlet).

```
...
<filter>
  <filter-name>filter_name</filter-name>
  <filter-class>filter_class</filter-class>
</filter>
...
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>filter_name</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>servlet_name_1</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>filter_name</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>servlet_name_2</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
...
```

#### See also

- [The Essentials of Filters](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html#74035)